# Web interface for photo/video gallery with access tokens

Tags: web, gallery

I'm searching for some sort of web interface to install on my linux nas (armhf, ubuntu 16.04) that would allow me to share folders containing pictures and videos with my friends and family. It should allow browsing (thumbnail view), viewing images and videos in-browser and saving them locally.

I've looked at Owncloud, but it's too complex and don't want to set up accounts. I'm looking for something like Picasa Web Albums where you could share a folder privately (with a key in the url). Bonus points if you can revoke the key a few hours after the first use or at least lock it to the IP that made the first connection to it. Also, bonus points if the interface allows download of the whole album locally (e.g. as a zip archive).

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: 1) IMHO between managing access via "keys" or via accounts does not make much difference... just you can easier get a mess with thousands of keys. **||** 2) i'm not sure what you mean with *"share a folder **privately** (with a **key in the url**)"*... but for me it sounds like a hoax! - i guess this is [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and thus NOT secure. a URL is basically public and everybody who knows/guesses it can access it, except it is locked by any other access data - you guess right - you have to manage.

Comment: concerning owncloud (although i recommend [Nextcloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nextcloud)): everything you asked for, can be done with it! 1) you don't have to setup accounts, you can. 2) you can also share links for folders and files public with a random URL. 3) you can set shares to automatically disappear after a given time. 4) download of a folder at once is also possible. ADDITIONALLY: for sure you can also really protect "public shares" with passwords.

Comment: btw: you can [edit the config.php](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/12/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#user-experience) and via `'defaultapp' => 'gallery',` set the gallery-app to be the default one to make it more convenient for your use-case.

Comment: last but not least: in general locking sharing-URLs to the first IP which connects to it won't make much sense, since its functionality will depend on how you share this link. - there are several messengers, webmail-provider or also just mail-provider which scan your messages and also check URLs in it!

Comment: Thank you for your pointers.

Yes, having a unique key is security by obscurity, but should be enough for my case. Also, I do not plan on giving out too many keys. About 10 or so would be valid at one point.

I will look at nextcloud, but I am not looking for something like dropbox specifically. I'll also try the default gallery view. 

There's one thing I didn't like about owncloud - you had to add your files to its data directory. This means that if I want to share 3 folders from /nas/Pictures I need to share /nas/Pictures which is unsafe IMHO.

Comment: 1) to avoid misunderstandings in future please avoid *"key"* in this context, it is just a weak random string. **||** 2) *security by obscurity* is just bad practice, so (i) try to avoid it anyway! - public is public, either it is a name, number or a random string. --> do you know what the scanners are doing with the URLs? just a ping to say "hallo"; i doubt it! a screenshot, index the site or completely download it; who knows? - and at the worst case your images ending at googles search-engine, although they were "secured" by a hoax-key.

Comment: well nextcloud is even much more than dropbox (especially with its countless apps, you can also deactivate)...! :-/ all other real/just gallery-systems i know are either public or/and restricted by accounts and groups. so if you want to selective share (protected) links, this is the only way i know. --> nextcloud is not a real answer, thus just the comments.

Comment: em... no! - use the web-interface just go to the folder(s) you want to share and share it. the parent folder and its containing files stay private! otherwise the whole thing won't make much sense. i don't know how it is implemented by your NAS but that's what permissions are for. **||** for sure all files has to be in the data folder (this won't be different for other CMS), because otherwise the server won't find your files. - for sure you can work with links, but that would make it even more complex.